# Change collection to query builder in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

I have a function with return type **Builder**

For some specific case, i need to **change the value of collection** (which i'll get from builder object) and **return updated value as builder object**.

**Is there any way to convert a collection back to it's builder object?**

Here is what i want to achieve in simpler form:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('is_human',1);    // Builder obj

$isAlien = true; 

$users = $users->get()->map(function($user) use ($isAlien) {
   $user->is_human = $isAlien? 0 : 1;
   return $user;
});
```

Now, the problem is when i execute this code, **it will return a collection**.

But **i want to return $users as Builder Object.**

I have searched through the laravel's API document to find a solution.

Please share your knowledge.